# Как сделать вертикальные и горизонтальные линии как в макете?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С цифрами и текстом я справился, а вот как сделать красную вертикальную красную и горизонтальные белые между текстом и цифрами у меня что-то не получается.

Comment: Псевдоэлемент `:after` или `:before`. 
Для `:first-child` будет `:before` (красная линия), а для каждой цифры будет `:after` (белая линия). P.S. Код скинь, тогда помогу сделать..

Answer (score 3):

```css
.vertical-line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.horizontal-line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
Vertical line:
<div class="vertical-line"></div>
<br/><br/> Horizontal line:
<div class="horizontal-line"></div>
```